# How to get the value from the most detailed hierarchy row

Tags: oracle-12c

I have a table with the following structure:

| Country | State | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BR | SP | qwert | 10 |
| BR | SP | yrtu | 12 |
| BR | SP |  | 13 |
| BR |  |  | 14 |
| BR | RJ | zxc | 11 |
| BR |  | iop | 9 |

This table contains a multiplicative value that I need to checkup based on the information I have on a client table

| Client | Country | State | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cli1 | BR | SP |  |
| cli2 | BR |  | qwert |

I need to get only the value based on the most detailed on the hierarchy, so if a city value is filled, I only get the row for that city.

The city names are unique and the country is not null.

I tried the query below, however, with `cli1` I ended up with duplicate rows

```sql
    SELECT
        "c"."Client",
        "c"."Country",
        "c"."State",
        "c"."City",
        "v"."Value"
    FROM
        "Clients" AS "c"
        LEFT JOIN "Values" AS "v" ON (
            ("c"."City" = "v"."City" OR "v"."City" IS NULL) AND
            ("c"."State" = "v"."State" OR "v"."State" IS NULL) AND
            ("c"."Country" = "v"."Country")
        )
```

And I need to get the following result:

| Client | Country | State | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cli1 | BR | SP |  | 13 |
| cli2 | BR |  | quert | 10 |